# Comparison between rational software architect(RSA) & rational application developer(RAD) IBM products

Tags: ide, ibm-rad

It seems ***Rational software architect*** (RSA) & ***Rational application developer*** (RAD) both IBM products are basically used as an IDE. But both have specific purpose to use. Please help me to understand when to use RSA and when RAD. What are the differences and what are the similarities between these two IBM products.

Comment: Checkout out http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039617

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAD is a commercial Eclipse-based integrated development environment (IDE), made by IBM's Rational Software division, for visually designing, constructing, testing, and deploying Web services, portals, and Java EE applications.

RSA is a modeling and development environment that uses the Unified Modeling Language (UML) for designing architecture for C++ and Java EE applications and web services. RSA is built on the Eclipse open-source software framework and includes capabilities focused on architectural code analysis, C++, and model-driven development (MDD) with the UML for creating applications and web services.

RSA includes all the capabilities of RAD and more!